# Fork-specific git log

Tags: git, logging, fork, commit

Is there any way to filter a git log to the commits specific to a fork, given it didn't keep the upstream tags? If so, how can it be done?

For example, I want to know what are the commits in the [Samsung Linux kernel fork](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=kernel/samsung.git;a=summary) didn't come from the [Torvalds Linux kernel tree](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=summary).

Thank you,

Rafael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you would need to have all commits from both repositories in a single local repository. Then you need to know the head commits of both repositories.

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
cd linux
git remote add -f samsung git://android.git.kernel.org/kernel/samsung.git
```

After you've done this, it's simple.
Ask git to provide a log of "reachable from samsung, but not reachable from Linus' tree":

```
git log origin/master..samsung/master
# which is equivalent to
git log ^origin/master samsung/master
# and
git log samsung/master --not origin/master
```

Comment: That doesn't provide all commits that are unique to that fork, just those that are in the fork's `master`, but not in the original's `master`. Which might be what the OP wanted (or close enough). And it will give bad results if a commit that's in both branches was rebased in one of them.

Comment: @svick: yes, for multiple branches in samsung remote you have to name all of them. and rebased commits are different commits (even though they might introduce the same changes), so that argument does not count ;)